# ORACLE Constraint to allow Null Value, IF

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I'm working with oracle for the first time, and I have a table called ExpenseReport which stores details about expenses.

I want Nulls to be allowed for ApprUserNo IF ERStatus = 'PENDING'
Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been trying to sort this all morning

```
CREATE TABLE ExpenseReport 
(
  ERNo           NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
  ERDesc         VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
  ERSubmitDate   DATE NOT NULL,
  ERStatusDate   DATE NOT NULL,
  ERStatus       VARCHAR2(8) DEFAULT 'PENDING' NOT NULL,
  SubmitUserNo   NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
  ApprUserNo     NUMBER(10) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT BEN_Check CHECK (ERStatus LIKE('PENDING')),
  UsersUserNo    NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
  AssetAssetNo   NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ERNo),
  CONSTRAINT Check_ER_Date CHECK (ERStatusDate >= ERSubmitDate),
  CONSTRAINT ERStatus_Null_Exception CHECK (IF ERStatus = 'PENDING',AppUserNo = NULLABLE),
  CONSTRAINT ERStatus_Option CHECK (ERStatus = 'PENDING','APPROBED','DENIED')
)
```

Comment: I need ApprUserNo to be Nullable ONLY IF ERStatus = 'Pending'

Comment: I'm getting an error when I try to execute this.

Comment: Oh boy... *And which error*? We don't do magic here, how do you think are we supposed to know your error if you aren't telling us?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to re-form your constraints.

First, if you ever want a field to hold nulls, regardless of any other rules, it must be a nullable field.

```
ApprUserNo     NUMBER(10)   NULL,   -- No Check Constrain
```

Second, create a constraint that says ApprUserNo can not be NULL, unless `ErStatus = 'PENDING'`

```
CONSTRAINT ERStatus_Null_Exception CHECK (AppUserNo IS NOT NULL OR ERStatus = 'PENDING'),
```

Comment: DEMS Thanks a million, you've saved my ass! Cheers everyone! Much Love.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
CONSTRAINT ERStatus_Null_Exception 
     CHECK (ERStatus <> 'PENDING' AND AppUserNo IS NOT NULL)
```

You should also change:
`CONSTRAINT BEN_Check CHECK (ERStatus LIKE('PENDING'))`
to
`CONSTRAINT BEN_Check CHECK (ERStatus = 'PENDING')`
because a) LIKE is not a function and b) LIKE without wildcards does not make sense.


Then you have another error here: 
`CONSTRAINT ERStatus_Option CHECK (ERStatus = 'PENDING','APPROBED','DENIED')`
that should be 
`CONSTRAINT ERStatus_Option CHECK (ERStatus IN ('PENDING','APPROBED','DENIED'))`

Please re-read the chapter in the Oracle manual that documents the syntax for CREATE TABLE and SQL conditions.

Comment: Plus, make the field nullable in the first place.  The OP has it as `NOT NULL` at present, which is peculiar if the OP ever wants NULLs in it...

Comment: @Dems: good catch, I didn't pay attention to the column definitions, only to the expressions for the check constraints.

Comment: Also, why isn't your first contraint `(ERStatus = 'PENDING' OR AppUserNo IS NULL)`?  Am I missing something?  *(Quite possible, long week already)*

Comment: @Dems - in fact: `(ERStatus = 'PENDING' OR AppUserNo IS NOT NULL)`

Comment: @TonyAndrews - Doh, yeah.  See, did say it was a long week!

Comment: Thanks for your Reply Daniel.
I have changed my code to:

 ApprUserNo   number(10) 
  CONSTRAINT BEN_Check 
  CHECK (ERStatus = 'PENDING'),
  CONSTRAINT ERStatus_Null_Exception 
  CHECK (ERStatus <> 'PENDING' AND AppUserNo IS NOT NULL)

Unfortunately I am getting an error: 'Column check constraint can not reference other columns'

Any ideas whats wrong?

Comment: @Ben: you need to move that check constraint to the end in order to use it as a table level check constraint.