# mysql not to allow NULL on unique index

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oracle, mysql-workbench

i created a table using mysql of users.
columns of the table are sequence, email, date_created and date_canceled.
primary is sequence and im trying to make a unique index for email and date_canceled - so when email is active (never been canceled - means date_canceled is NULL) there wont be another active email inserted or a situation of this happening.

i know its can be done with oracle db but with mysql unique indexs allow NULL.

any suggestions how to handle this??
thanks!

Comment: Have you tried applying `NOT NULL` to your index?

Comment: dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10009219/oracle-constraint-to-allow-null-value-if

Comment: i want to allow null on date_canceled column because that way i'll know its active...

Comment: @ficuscr - not a dupe.  10009219 asked about a "conditional" NOT NULL constraint, which is different than what OP is asking for here.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of your question is that you want each user to have one active email associated with them at any time, also keeping a history of users' previous mails.

---

**Solution 1**

As of MySQL 5.7.5 you can do this by creating a generated column and then putting a unique constraint on that; http://mysqlserverteam.com/generated-columns-in-mysql-5-7-5/.
e.g.

```
create table UniqueActiveEmailDemo 
(
    sequence bigint not null auto_increment primary key
  , userId bigint not null
  , email nvarchar(1024) not null
  , date_created timestamp default now()
  , date_cancelled datetime
  , single_active_mail_per_user bigint as (if(date_cancelled is null, userId, null))
);

alter table UniqueActiveEmailDemo 
add unique UK_UniqueActiveEmailDemo_SingleActiveMailPerUser 
(single_active_mail_per_user);
```

Because MySQL allows multiple nulls in a unique constraint, where the record is cancelled, the generate column has a null value; so you can have as many of those records as you like.  However if the record isn't cancelled, the generated column returns the user's id; this is subject to the unique constraint, so if there's another active record with the same user id the unique constraint will throw an exception.

---

**Solution 2**

Sql Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b54dce/2

However a cleaner method which also works with earlier versions would be to simply prevent date_cancelled from being nullable; instead setting it to a fixed value in the far future for any items not yet cancelled, then have the combination of user_id and date_cancelled be null; e.g.

```
create table UniqueActiveEmailDemo 
(
  sequence bigint not null auto_increment primary key
  , userId bigint not null
  , email nvarchar(1024) not null
  , date_created timestamp default now()
  , date_cancelled datetime not null default '9999-12-31 23:59:59'
);

ALTER TABLE UniqueActiveEmailDemo 
ADD UNIQUE UK_UniqueActiveEmailDemo_SingleActiveMailPerUser 
(userId, date_cancelled);
```

- One difference here is you can't have two records for the same user cancelled on the same date; but in reality I assume you'd never get that anyway.
- It also means you can have records which get in the future.  To avoid this issue you can either treat `9999-12-31 23:59:59` as you had null values; i.e. whatever record has that value is active.
- You could also get around the above issue by adding an `active_from` date and filter on `where now() between date_active and date_cancelled`; however you'd then need to add more checks to ensure that active windows for the same user didn't overlap; which further complicates things.
- Adding a check constraint would protect against future values; but sadly they're not currently used in MySQL (though are valid statements). http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html

`, date_cancelled datetime not null default '9999-12-31 23:59:59' 
   check (date_cancelled = '9999-12-31 23:59:59' or date_cancelled <= now())`

Answer (score 0):

The BDB storage engine will treat `NULL` as a unique value, only allowing a single `NULL` value.

[From the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/bdb-restrictions.html):

> If a column that permits `NULL` values has a unique index, only a single
>   `NULL` value is permitted. This differs from other storage engines,
>   which permit multiple `NULL` values in unique indexes.

If you don't want to change your storage engine to get this behavior, your other options would be to change your table structure to store active e-mails and cancelled e-mails in different tables... create a trigger to enforce this behavior... or assign a magic date value for `active` e-mails, and no longer allow `NULL` values in this column.